# Wikipedia proof Fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: real-analysis

FTC part I says that

"If $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous then $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable with $F'(x) = f(x)$ on $(a,b)$."

Proof of fact that $F$ is differentiable is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Proof_of_the_first_part) where mean value theorem is used:

"According to the mean value theorem for integration, there exists a $c$ in $[x_1, x_1 + \Delta x]$ such that $$ \int_{x_1}^{x_1 + \Delta x} f(t) dt = f(c) \Delta x$$"

But mean value theorem says if $F$ is continuous on $[x_1, x_1 + \Delta x]$ and differentiable on $(x_1, x_1 + \Delta x)$ then there is such $c$. But that $F$ is differentiable on $(x_1, x_1 + \Delta x)$ is what this proof is proving therefore we can't assume it.

Is this proof on Wikipedia wrong? If not, why can we apply MVT (mean value theorem) to show that $F$ is differentiable when we need $F$ to be differentiable in order to apply MVT? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.
In the proof of the [mean value theorem for integration](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Mean_Value_Theorem_for_Integrals) we use the  intermediate value theorem and not the mean value theorem.

Comment: @blue: The MVT that you are used to requires differentiability, but there is an analogous result for integrals, where $F$ plays the role of $f'$ in MVT, and so $\int_b^aF(t)dt$ plays the role of $f$. (The proof on Wikipedia for MVT$\int$ does not rely on the FToC, so this is a valid maneuver)